# grape-entity represent not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api, grape-entity

I am using `grape` gem for `API` and `grape-entity` to generate responses.

Simple `show/get` request is responding fine like returning only data from `ActiveRecord Object`.  **Fine**

When i try to include data from `has_many` relation it return all the data related to that object. **Fine**

But when I `represent` data like

```
post = Post.first
data = V1::Entities::PostEntities.represent(post, only: [:id, { comments: [:id, :body] }])
data.as_json
```

It should return something like this as per [documentation](https://github.com/intridea/grape-entity#returning-only-the-fields-you-want):

```
{
  id: 1,
  comments: [{
    id: 1,
    body: 'example'
  }]
}
```

**But** it returns:

```
{
  id: 1,
  comments: [{
    id: 1,
    user_id: 1,
    body: 'example',
    created_at: 'some_timestamp',
    updated_at: 'also_some_timestamp',
    is_deleted: 0,
  }]
}
```

My `PostEntities` contains:

```
module V1
  module Entities
    class PostEntities < Grape::Entity
      expose :id
      expose :comments, with: V1::Entities::CommentEntities
    end
  end
end
```

My `CommentEntities` contains:

```
module V1
  module Entities
    class CommentEntities < Grape::Entity
      expose :id
      expose :user_id
      expose :body
      expose :created_at
      expose :updated_at
      expose :is_deleted
    end
  end
end
```

**there is something wrong with `represent` method. i am not getting what the issue is?**

Answer (score 1):

Check out the grape [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/intridea/grape-entity/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), and you will find out that the represent function will work in next version(0.4.6).

0.4.6 (Next) #114: Added 'only' option that selects which attributes should be returned - @estevaoam.

So, if you want to use this function right now, you can use the newest github version.

`gem 'grape-entity', github: "intridea/grape-entity", branch: "master"`